# How to get a single tooltip when there are multiple lineBarsData FlChart

Tags: flutter, dart, fl-chart

I'm using this package https://pub.dev/packages/fl_chart and
and there is the possibility of when you move the mouse over a line of the graph to show a tooltip with the data but of all the lines on the graph.

This is what happen now. I attach an example below:

[image: it get both lines]

I would need to have a single tooltip and not for all lines in the graph. I attach an example below:
[image: this is what I would like to achieve]

Answer (score 3):

Until this point I'm using a workaround by setting a flag which tells me which data could be added inside the LineToolTipItem.

```
getTooltipItems: (List<LineBarSpot> touchedBarSpots) {
                bool first = true;
                return touchedBarSpots.map((barSpot) {
                  if (first) {
                    first = false;
                    return LineTooltipItem(
                      barSpot.x + barSpot.y,
                    );
                  }
                }).toList();
              }),
```

If you have more than 2 chart lines, I suggest to have an integer variable which will give you the proper line data index to be used inside your tool tip.

Answer (score 0):

:)

You could do the following. This worked for me.

```
getTooltipItems: (List<LineBarSpot> touchedBarSpots) {
                                  bool first = true;
                                  return touchedBarSpots.map((barSpot) {
                                    if (first) {
                                      first = false;
                                      return LineTooltipItem(
                                        'STD: ' + barSpot.y.toString(), TextStyle()
                                      );
                                    }
                                    else{
                                      first = true;
                                      return LineTooltipItem(
                                          'ACT: ' + barSpot.y.toString(), TextStyle()
                                      );
                                    }
                                  }).toList();
                                },

Thank you very much. :)
```